# How can I assign '0' element count to the variable?

Tags: cypress

I get element with class and find its children. I need to get count of children element and assigned to variable currentCount. After there I make some actions and need to compare element counts in the end.

```
 const currentCount = cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
    .first()
    .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
    .its('length')

  // do actions


  cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
    .first()
    .children(".Day:not(.Day--disabled)")
    .its('length')
    .then(nextCount => {
      currentCount.should('not.eq', nextCount)
    })
```

html:

```
  <div class="DayContainer current">
    <div class="Day Day--disabled"></div>   // first                                                      
    <div class="Day" 
         data-date="Wed Jul 14 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)">
    </div>                                 //second
    <span data-date="Wed Jul 14 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)" class="Date">14</span>
  </div>
```

Problem with values. The element DayContainer can has children 0, 1, 2.
My test falls, because DayContainer can has class 'Day--disabled' in the both elements after actions.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I use [array prototype find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for such actions:

Cypress command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getNumberOfDuplicateElements", (parent, duplicateElementSelector, alias) => {
    cy.log('getNumberOfDuplicateElements')
    return cy.get(parent).then((parentElement) => {
        if (parentElement.find(duplicateElementSelector).length > 0) {
            cy.get(duplicateElementSelector)
                .its('length')
                .as(alias)
        } else {
            cy.wrap(0).as(alias)
        }

    })
})
```

Code usage:

```
cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
    .first()
    .then(parentElement => {
        cy.getNumberOfDuplicateElements(parentElement, `.Day:not(.Day--disabled)`, 'currentCount')
    })
cy.get('@currentCount')
    .then(currentCount => {
        //code to use it
    })
```

Comment: I added your code. But it isn't decide my problem.
I get element .DayContainer which consist of the 2 element with class .Day. And one, two or zero elements can have also class .Day--Disabled. After my actions number of . .Day--disabled element can changed. And I need compare count  of elements with class .Day before and after actions.

Comment: After the action that changes the state - put an assertion that it is changed or a `cy.wait` and then use my code

Answer (score 0):

Counting elements is a big weakness in Cypress commands because of built-in "existence assertion", which means if the selector does not exist the test will automatically fail.

In your case, you have two classes `Day` and `Day--disabled` and you want to count the 2nd and compare after an action.

Separate the two classes, use the 1st to get the children and the 2nd to filter and count the ones not disabled.

Use jQuery to filter because it has no built-in existence assertion.

This is my test DOM based on your sample. I added a button to make both divs disabled.

```html
<div class="DayContainer current">
  <div class="Day Day--disabled"></div>   // first                                                      
  <div class="Day" 
       data-date="Wed Jul 14 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)">
  </div>                                 //second
  <span data-date="Wed Jul 14 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)" class="Date">14</span>
</div>

<button>Disable Today</button>

<script>
  const button = document.querySelector('button')
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const day = document.querySelector('div.Day[data-date*="Jul 14 2021"]')
    day.classList.add('Day--disabled')
  })
</script>
```

This is the test

```js
const todaysDate = '14'

cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day")
  .then($els => $els.filter(':not(.Day--disabled)').length )
  .as('currentCount')

cy.get('button').contains('Disable Today').click()

cy.get(`.DayContainer:contains('${todaysDate}')`)
  .first()
  .children(".Day")
  .then($els => $els.filter(':not(.Day--disabled)').length )
  .then(nextCount => {
    cy.get('@currentCount').then(currentCount => {

      expect(currentCount).not.eq(nextCount)
      cy.wrap(currentCount).should('not.eq', nextCount)  // same as previous line

    })
  })
```

**Notes - jQuery filter**

Use `.children(".Day")` to get the children because they always have that class, so it will always succeed.

Use `.then($els => $els.filter(':not(.Day--disabled)').length )` to filter and find the length, all using jQuery inside a callback. The result is a number from 0 to max children.

Do not use

```
.filter(':not(.Day--disabled)')
.its('length')
```

because the Cypress filter command also has built-in existence assertion.

---

**Notes - saving Chainer**

I did not use `const currentCount = cy.get(...)` because this saves the ***query*** and not the ***value***, so later on  `currentCount.should(..)` re-runs the query with the new DOM, so it will fail to find any difference in count.

This is why there are not many examples of using the return value (Chainer), because it does not snapshot the value.

Instead, use the more common **alias** `.as('currentCount')` and `cy.get('@currentCount').then(currentCount =>`.